# Excel Subtract BY Group

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ifs

| STUDENT | CLASS | TIME | GRADE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | A | 2 | 8 |
| 1 | A | 3 | 6 |
| 1 | B | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | B | 2 | 9 |
| 2 | A | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | B | 1 | 6 |
| 2 | C | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | C | 2 | 0 |

I have the data above and wish for this data below,

| STUDENT | CLASS | TIME | GRADE | WANT1 | WANT2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 5 | 3 | -2 |
| 1 | A | 2 | 8 | 3 | -2 |
| 1 | A | 3 | 6 | 3 | -2 |
| 1 | B | 1 | 2 | 7 |  |
| 1 | B | 2 | 9 | 7 |  |
| 2 | A | 1 | 2 |  |  |
| 2 | B | 1 | 6 |  |  |
| 2 | C | 1 | 3 | -3 |  |
| 2 | C | 2 | 0 | -3 |  |

with the rules,

```
WANT1 == for each STUDENT and CLASS combination, GRADE(TIME = 2) - GRADE(TIME = 1)
WANT2 == for each STUDENT and CLASS combination, GRADE(TIME = 3) - GRADE(TIME = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Subtract Filtered Data

- Both solutions work for the presented sample data.

**XLOOKUP**

- This is more efficient but doesn't allow `Time` duplicates for unique `Student/Class` values.

```
=LET(data,$A$2:$D$10,smaller_times,{1;2},greater_times,{2;3},
    ds,CHOOSECOLS(data,1),
    dc,CHOOSECOLS(data,2),
    dt,CHOOSECOLS(data,3),
    dg,CHOOSECOLS(data,4),
MAKEARRAY(ROWS(data),COUNT(smaller_times),LAMBDA(r,c,LET(
    fsc,(ds=INDEX(ds,r))*(dc=INDEX(dc,r)),
    ts,XLOOKUP(1,fsc*(dt=INDEX(smaller_times,c)),dg),
    tg,XLOOKUP(1,fsc*(dt=INDEX(greater_times,c)),dg),
IFERROR(tg-ts,"")))))
```

[image]

**SUM/FILTER**

- This is less efficient but allows `Time` duplicates for unique `Student/Class` values.

```
=LET(data,$A$2:$D$10,smaller_times,{1;2},greater_times,{2;3},
    ds,CHOOSECOLS(data,1),
    dc,CHOOSECOLS(data,2),
    dt,CHOOSECOLS(data,3),
    dg,CHOOSECOLS(data,4),
MAKEARRAY(ROWS(data),COUNT(smaller_times),LAMBDA(r,c,LET(
    fsc,(ds=INDEX(ds,r))*(dc=INDEX(dc,r)),
    ts,SUM(FILTER(dg,fsc*(dt=INDEX(smaller_times,c)))),
    tg,SUM(FILTER(dg,fsc*(dt=INDEX(greater_times,c)))),
IFERROR(tg-ts,"")))))
```

Answer (score 1):

WANT1:

```
=MAP(A2:A10,B2:B10,LAMBDA(x,y,IFERROR(FILTER(D2:D10,(A2:A10=x) 
 * (B2:B10=y) * (C2:C10=2))-FILTER(D2:D10,(A2:A10=x) * (B2:B10=y) 
 * (C2:C10=1)),"")))
```

WANT2:

```
=MAP(A2:A10,B2:B10,LAMBDA(x,y,IFERROR(FILTER(D2:D10,(A2:A10=x) 
 * (B2:B10=y) * (C2:C10=3))-FILTER(D2:D10,(A2:A10=x) * (B2:B10=y) 
 * (C2:C10=2)),"")))
```

Can't attach a screenshot since i'm a new user. The sample data is in range `A2:A10` (STUDENT), `B2:B10` (CLASS), `C2:C10` (TIME) and `D2:D10` (GRADE).The formulas can be entered in cells `E2` (WANT1) and `F2` (WANT2).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts in cell `A1`, here's one possible solution:

For the "WANT1" column, use the following formula in cell `E2` and copy it down:

```
=IF(PRODUCT(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10, A2, $B$2:$B$10, B2, $C$2:$C$10, {1,2}))>0,
MMULT(SUMIFS($D$2:$D$10, $A$2:$A$10, A2, $B$2:$B$10, B2, $C$2:$C$10, {1,2}), {-1;1}), "")
```

For the "WANT2" column, use the following formula in cell `F2` and copy it down:

```
=IF(PRODUCT(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10, A2, $B$2:$B$10, B2, $C$2:$C$10, {2,3}))>0,
MMULT(SUMIFS($D$2:$D$10, $A$2:$A$10, A2, $B$2:$B$10, B2, $C$2:$C$10, {2,3}), {-1;1}), "")
```

**NOTE:** with older versions of Excel, be sure to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

With Office 365, the above methods can be combined into a single array formula in cell `E2`:

```
=LET(
rng, A2:D10,
_c1, INDEX(rng,, 1),
_c2, INDEX(rng,, 2),
_c3, INDEX(rng,, 3),
_c4, INDEX(rng,, 4),
MAKEARRAY(ROWS(rng), 2, LAMBDA(r,c,
   IF(PRODUCT(COUNTIFS(_c1, INDEX(_c1, r), _c2, INDEX(_c2, r), _c3, SEQUENCE(, 2, c)))>0,
   MMULT(SUMIFS(_c4, _c1, INDEX(_c1, r), _c2, INDEX(_c2, r), _c3, SEQUENCE(, 2, c)), {-1;1}), "")))
)
```

To create a condensed summary by STUDENT & CLASS:

```
=LET(
rng, A2:D10,
_c1, INDEX(rng,, 1),
_c2, INDEX(rng,, 2),
_c3, INDEX(rng,, 3),
_c4, INDEX(rng,, 4),
lst, UNIQUE(A2:B10),
arr, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(lst), 2, LAMBDA(r,c,
   IF(PRODUCT(COUNTIFS(_c1, INDEX(lst, r, 1), _c2, INDEX(lst, r, 2), _c3, SEQUENCE(, 2, c)))>0,
   MMULT(SUMIFS(_c4, _c1, INDEX(lst, r, 1), _c2, INDEX(lst, r, 2), _c3, SEQUENCE(, 2, c)), {-1;1}), ""))),
VSTACK({"STUDENT","CLASS","WANT1","WANT2"}, HSTACK(lst, arr))
)
```

**Results:**

[image: countifs_sumifs_lambda.png]

Adjust the range references to meet your needs. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Similar idea to @user22566114. The question assumes there is a single value for each case that match the conditions, so we can use `FILTER` function as follows:

```
=LET(in,A2:D10, A,INDEX(in,,1), B,INDEX(in,,2), C,INDEX(in,,3), D,INDEX(in,,4),
 CALC, LAMBDA(ta,tb, MAP(A,B,C,D, LAMBDA(aa,bb,cc,dd,
  LET(fa,FILTER(D,(C=ta)*(A=aa)*(B=bb),""),
   fb,FILTER(D,(C=tb)*(A=aa)* (B=bb),""),
    IF(OR(@fa="", @fb=""), "", IF(ROWS(fa)*ROWS(fb)=1,fa-fb,"ERROR")))))),
 HSTACK(CALC(2,1), CALC(3,2)))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output1]

To avoid repetition of similar calculations we create a user `LAMBDA` function `CALC`, then we call it with the specific parameters for each column. The `IF` condition identifies the following scenarios:

1. `OR(@fa="", @fb="")` any empty filter result, then it returns an empty string.
2. `IF(ROWS(fa)*ROWS(fb)=1`: The filter result is a single row on each case (the assumption we are considering), so we return `fa-fb`.
3. Else, then it warns the assumption is not valid returning an `ERROR` string for the given rows.

If we replace `C4`: `3 -> 2`. The approach provided by @user22566114 returns `#CALC!`, for the entire result, so we don't know where is the issue. Under this approach it indicates the lines that don't satisfy the condition with the `ERROR` token, so the user can easily identify the issue and correct the input values:

[image: output2]